# Doctrine select count if

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have that query and want to translate it to doctrine

```
SELECT 
    ex.id,
    ex.title AS 'title of examination',
    SUM(IF(su.status_id = 2, 1, 0)) AS 'published surveys',
    SUM(IF(su.status_id = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'other surveys'
FROM
    examination ex
        LEFT JOIN
    survey su ON ex.id = su.examination_id
GROUP BY ex.id;
```

I know I can use `$qb->select("[SQL_HERE]")` but it wont be available to work with other databases, only my current(MySQL).

So, how can I encode this query to doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pure Doctrine cross database solution, you can:

1. Create your own Doctrine functions or use bundle for it
   (https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)
2. Or you can change the database, for example add column `published`
   that could have value 0 or 1 (and value of this column could be
   updated by trigger, if you want to keep your original `status_id`
   column) and then you can use pure doctrine query:

   `SELECT SUM(published) as count_published FROM ...`

(similarly for other surverys you could use another column `other` ...)